# Behaviour of $\tan$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

What happens to $\tan(u+iv)$ as $u^2+v^2\to \infty$ via a path where $v\neq 0$ and $u,v\in \mathbb R$? How can I tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may begin by applying the definition $\tan z=\frac{\sin z}{\cos z}$ getting :
$$\tan(u+iv)=\frac 1i \frac{e^{iu-v}-e^{-iu+v}}{e^{iu-v}+e^{-iu+v}}=\frac 1i \frac{e^{2iu-2v}-1}{e^{2iu-2v}+1}=\frac 1i \frac{e^{-2v}-e^{-2iu}}{e^{-2v}+e^{-2iu}}$$
You may try to rewrite this further (expanding $e^{-2iu}$, multiplying by the conjugate and so on) but I'll stop here and observe :

- a periodicity of $\pi$ for $u$ : $\tan(u+k\pi+iv)=\tan(u+iv)$
- $\tan(u+iv) \sim i\ $ as $v\to +\infty$
- $\tan(u+iv) \sim -i\ $ as $v\to -\infty$

A picture of the imaginary part of $\tan(u+iv)$ could perhaps help too :
[image: Im(tan)]$

An here is the real part :
[image]

Comment: Very nice graphics!

Comment: @Johanna: Thanks! It's an earlier version of MuPAD at work.